# How do I get the processor factory to transport their goods to the trading depot?

Tags: simcity-2013

On Sim City 5, I have two factories producing processors. I put a trading Depot right next to each one, but both factories say that they stopped production because they're full. I bought the maximum amount of trucks for both the factories and the depots. I also have three trading depots, with multiple lots for oil, ore, and freight, but it won't give me a Trading HQ, because it says that I only have two lots and I need three.

It's frustrating watching the computer chip flash yellow saying that the plant is full while the trading port next door sits empty.

Answer (score 4):

Your trading depot needs to have lots for processors specifically, not just 'freight'.

Comment: I just saw that on the choices of lots. Thank you!